# R doSNOW stopCLuster(cl) resulting in mpi exit

Tags: r, mpi

I have setup a mpi cluster. It runs on centos, with openmpi.
I am trying to run an R job, however and despite the job is run properly, it results in an error. Which does not make any sense to me. Any ideas why does this happen? Am i not properly stoping mpi on the R code?

dosnow.r

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

hello.world <- function(i) {
   sprintf('Hello from loop iteration %d running on rank %d on node %s',
       i, mpi.comm.rank(), Sys.info()[c("nodename")]);
}

library(foreach)
library(snow)
library(doSNOW)

cl <- makeMPIcluster( 3 )
registerDoSNOW(cl)

output.lines <- foreach(i = (1:10)) %dopar% {
   hello.world(i)
}

cat(unlist(output.lines), sep='\n')

stopCluster(cl)
```

mpirun

```
mpirun --hostfile wwhosts R CMD BATCH dosnow.r
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun has exited due to process rank 0 with PID 3200 on
node wwmaster exiting improperly. There are three reasons this could occur:

1. this process did not call "init" before exiting, but others in
the job did. This can cause a job to hang indefinitely while it waits
for all processes to call "init". By rule, if one process calls "init",
then ALL processes must call "init" prior to termination.

2. this process called "init", but exited without calling "finalize".
By rule, all processes that call "init" MUST call "finalize" prior to
exiting or it will be considered an "abnormal termination"

3. this process called "MPI_Abort" or "orte_abort" and the mca parameter
orte_create_session_dirs is set to false. In this case, the run-time cannot
detect that the abort call was an abnormal termination. Hence, the only
error message you will receive is this one.

This may have caused other processes in the application to be
terminated by signals sent by mpirun (as reported here).

You can avoid this message by specifying -quiet on the mpirun command line.

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Rout:

```
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10) -- "Wooden Christmas-Tree"
Copyright (C) 2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

[Previously saved workspace restored]

> #!/usr/bin/env Rscript
>
> hello.world <- function(i) {
+    sprintf('Hello from loop iteration %d running on rank %d on node %s',
+        i, mpi.comm.rank(), Sys.info()[c("nodename")]);
+ }
>
> library(foreach)
> library(snow)
> library(doSNOW)
Loading required package: iterators
>
> cl <- makeMPIcluster( 3 )
Loading required namespace: Rmpi
    3 slaves are spawned successfully. 0 failed.
> registerDoSNOW(cl)
>
> output.lines <- foreach(i = (1:10)) %dopar% {
+    hello.world(i)
+ }
>
> cat(unlist(output.lines), sep='\n')
Hello from loop iteration 1 running on rank 1 on node n0001.cluster
Hello from loop iteration 2 running on rank 2 on node wwmaster
Hello from loop iteration 3 running on rank 3 on node n0000.cluster
Hello from loop iteration 4 running on rank 1 on node n0001.cluster
Hello from loop iteration 5 running on rank 2 on node wwmaster
Hello from loop iteration 6 running on rank 3 on node n0000.cluster
Hello from loop iteration 7 running on rank 3 on node n0000.cluster
Hello from loop iteration 8 running on rank 1 on node n0001.cluster
Hello from loop iteration 9 running on rank 2 on node wwmaster
Hello from loop iteration 10 running on rank 1 on node n0001.cluster
>
> stopCluster(cl)
[1] 1
>
> proc.time()
   user  system elapsed
  0.835   0.290   4.177
```

Comment: I can indeed reproduce an issue, but it's with the `makeMPIcluster` function.

Comment: Don't you have the same problem if you use makeCluster(3, type='MPI') ?

Comment: Found the solution. Add Rmpi::mpi.quit() after stopCluster(cl).

Comment: Yes, mpi.quit() will call "finalize" which makes mpirun happy. Also, you should use the mpirun "-n 1" option, otherwise mpirun will start multiple processes, each of which will spawn three workers.